Can anyone suggest how to import any framework code into its sample app in Xcode 16
Can anyone suggest how to import any framework code into its sample app in Xcode 16.
In the Xcode 16 when i was creating a framework it generates a ".docc" file that contains the public source code & its is not accessible in their targeted sample app but able to import that module on the same.
In Xcode 15.3 & earlier it generates a "Library" folder that coatains the source code & can be easily accessible by the sample app.
